# Background Task failing due to Resource Revocation

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I'm in the midst of developing an app that functions somewhat like a podcatcher, and one of the features I would like to implement is a background task that keeps the latest episodes of subscribed series downloaded.

Unfortunately, in practice, the app can very rarely manage one complete download, with the task failing due to "resource revocation".

I appreciate the limitation, but when it seems impossible to download a 15mb file, I'm not quite sure how the OS is supposed to support podcatchers or similar apps.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried [BackgroundDownloader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but no download action, is a simple background task. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I have a similar problem